# how goji csrf not working with multipart

Tags: go, goji

I'm learning how to develop a website using go and I've decided to try Goji. Everything is working fine except when I'm trying to use CSRF (`goji-csrf`) on a file upload I keep getting `Forbidden - CSRF token invalid` but when I removed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the template the csrf middleware is working fine.

Thanks for the answer in advance guys.

Comment: I've merged in multipart form support to goji/csrf: https://github.com/goji/csrf/pull/4 (I'd missed this when merging in other commits from its sister-project, gorilla/csrf)

Comment: Thanks for the hard work